# How are Distributed Snapshot algorithms (likes of Chandy Lamport) implemented in real world distributed systems?

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems

Can anyone explain, how Distributed Snapshot algorithms ( Example: [Chandy-Lamport](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/chandy.pdf) are implemented in the context of  modern distributed systems?

Can you name an open source System implementation which uses this / these class of algorithm?

**How does this theory really translate to real world?**

Comment: Implementations and their issues are offtopic here. I suggest you try [SO].

Comment: I am being downvoted at stackoverflow for posting this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018235/how-are-distributed-snapshot-algorithms-likes-of-chandy-lamport-implemented-in

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to ask them why. Maybe because it's not about a piece of code yet.